# Users - Change Account Info Using Forms

Tags: django, forms, request

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zybcj.png)
[Urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0GUn.png) I was trying to create a site that is responsible for editing profile info:

Edit_profile.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}



{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and edit_profile is defined by:

```
def edit_profile(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
                form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('/Nornik/profile')

        else:
                form = UserChangeForm(instance=request.user)
                args = {'form': form}
                return render(request, 'Nornik/edit_profile.html', args)
```

Everything is working fine (system detects no issues.), I should be able to data like: name, second name, email etc, but what I recive is normal text, which I can't edit. Example (what I recive): Login
Username: johnbrown

First name: john

Last name: brown

Email: j.brown@gmail.com .I defined it it my file (in urls.py everything is set properly `re_path('profile/edit_profile/', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile')`). That's why i think that i should be able to edit that. Other articles on stackoverflow didn't help.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't really understand with what you mean with "*but what i recive as request is a site with login data, that I can't edit, although I defined it it my file*"?

Comment: I should be able to data like: name, second name, email etc, but what I recive is normal text, which I can't edit. Example (what I recive): Login
Username: johnbrown

First name: john

Last name: brown

Email: j.brown@gmail.com

Comment: It's still not entirely clear, can you share some screenshot or something that explains what the problem is?

Comment: Yes. I linked the screenshot of what i recive. I should recive a file where I can edit my login data while being a normal user. I recive text that I can't edit.

Comment: it looks like it is visting the wrong view, since it has not even a submit button. Can you share the entire `urls.py`?

Comment: I think that everything is ok, but I linked it.

Comment: what if you add a `$` at `profile/$` (not the one to edit the profile).

Comment: It works! Thank you. Does it mean that after register it should be also "$" sign?

Comment: yes, although nowadays path syntax is more in use, making it also easier to work with paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your `re_path` to view the profile has no end anchor, meaning it matches anything with `profile/` even if it does not end with this. You thus should add an ending achor `$`. You thus should include an anchor tag, or you can use [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urls/#django.urls.path):

```
path('profile/', views.profile, name='view_profile'),
```